# Change postfix name from "localhost" to something meaningful?

Tags: email, postfix

I run postfix my servers to allow websites to send email. I'm using it as a drop-in for `sendmail` proper.

When an email is sent the HELO string seems to contain `localhost`. This wouldn't be a problem except that one of my clients has just said that an email was returned to them from a spam blocker saying that `localhost` cannot feature inside the HELO string. Awesome.

So I edited `/etc/mailname` to be my main domain name. And I edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf` so that:

```
smtpd_banner = ESMTP $mail_name
```

Yet this is what I see in the header of a sent email (after restarting postfix):

```
Delivered-To: oli@example.com
Received: by 22.194.173.22 with SMTP id bi10csp117521wjc;
        Tue, 2 Apr 2013 07:24:18 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.68.22.168 with SMTP id pt8mr24540246pbb.10.1364912657736;
        Tue, 02 Apr 2013 07:24:17 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <oli@example.com>
Received: from localhost (example.com. [22.22.22.22])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id l6si2328296pao.283.2013.04.02.07.24.16;
        Tue, 02 Apr 2013 07:24:17 -0700 (PDT)
```

I've subbed my domain with example.com.

#### What do I need to edit to quash the evil reign of `localhost`?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hurrrrrr*.

I've *just* noticed that in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` there was a line that read:

```
myhostname = localhost
```

I've changed that to :

```
myhostname = example.com
```

And restarted. All is fixed.

Comment: I am trying this on Fedora 16.04 and even after a restart this does not work. I have set both `hostname` and `myorigin` to a real domain and the "evil regin" of localhost continues.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add `smtp_generic_maps` to the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Create the `/etc/postfix/generic` file if it does not exist. Say you want to replace root@localhost, then do:

```
root@localhost youruser@yourdomain.com
```

Add it to configuration and restart

```
 sudo postmap /etc/postfix/generic
 sudo service postfix restart
```

References: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html